# Reading IPs and manipulating URL with IP

Tags: api, python-2.7

I want to read a text file(ips.txt) with IP addresses in each line , 
Example file :

```
16.180.77.86
16.180.77.87
16.180.77.88
16.180.77.89
16.180.77.90
16.180.77.91
```

and then substitue that IP address in following url string "https://"+

I tried :

```
 readme=open("ips.txt","r")
 for readie in readme.readline():
     modi="https://"+ str(readie)+":8080/api/v1/credentials"
     print modi
```

But it replied:

> https://1:8080/api/v1/credentials

Any suggestions?

Comment: `for readie in readme` is enough, no need to add `readline()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `readme.readlines()`, not `readme.readline()`.

`readline()` returns a line from the file, so you iterate through a line, one character at a time. `readlines()` returns a list of strings, so you will iterate through each line.

Also, as @Morb suggested, `for readie in readme:` will work as well.